# IR remote heater

Tags: remote-control, infrared

I am having issues to reproduce the remote control of my heater , this is the dump of one button:

```
Encoding  : UNKNOWN
Code      : A32AB931 (32 bits)
Timing[23]: 
     +1300, - 400     +1250, - 450     + 400, -1250     +1250, - 450
     +1250, - 450     + 400, -1250     + 400, -1300     + 400, -1250
     + 400, -1300     + 400, -1250     + 400, -1300     +1250
unsigned int  rawData[23] = {1300,400, 1250,450, 400,1250, 1250,450, 1250,450, 400,1250, 400,1300, 400,1250, 400,1300, 400,1250, 400,1300, 1250};  // UNKNOWN A32AB931
```

I wonder why I cant just send the raw of this data, maybe because it doesnt run at 38khz? How do I find out what is the frequency ?

It worked fine to dump data from my tv and dvr so it is not an error n my code.

Note:
Opening the remote I found a BEC5104S which doesn't really tells me what frequency runs, not even the Chinese datahsheet

This is the spectrum which confirms that is working at 38khz
[image]

Comment: what IR library are you using? they should provide such methods...

Comment: Looks like [manchester encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code) to me. Were you able to emulate the TV/DVR remote?

Comment: I am using IRremote, the most common one. It works for my TV and DVR. It doesnt work for my heater. I am not sure if my heater is using a different frequency.

Comment: Update the post with spectrum which confirms that is working at 38khz